# Android 3 Scrollable TextViews

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I know how to make one TextView to be Scrollable, but how to do it with 3 TextViews? I just want to have one ScrollView with 3 TextViews inside it. Is it possible? How can I do this? My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    tools:context=".Info" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_scroll"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:text="„Hello"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Check my answer, please set it as accepted answer if it helped you. Rating is welcome too, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView can only contain 1 direct child.

If you want 3 Text View's scrollable, put them inside the ScrollView's child.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_scroll"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"        
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
             <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:text="„Hello"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:text="„Hello"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:text="„Hello"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```